# Not able to remove document from mongo in Node

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to remove a document from a mongo database using Node. Is something wrong with my .remove method here:

```
deleteApplicant : function(req,res){
    applicationModel.remove({_id:req.params.id} , function(err,count){
        res.redirect('/applicants');
        console.log(count)
    })
}
```

Am I using the correct syntax?

Comment: Did you try it ? did you have any error message ? At first sight, syntax seems goo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`_id` in the database is probably of type `ObjectId`, but you're passing a string to the query.

Try this instead:

```
var ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectID;
...
applicationModel.remove({ _id : ObjectId(req.params.id) }, ...)
```

Answer (score 0):

_id in the database would be of type ObjectId

try this

```
const { ObjectId } = require("mongodb");

...
collectionName.deleteOne({_id: new ObjectId(req.params.id),...}
```